# Migrate from Windows to Linux

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linux

I planned to migrate SQL Server 2008 Standard edition to Linux server instance. I have two problems with this instance:

1. How to activate this instance?
2. How to run instance in single mode to restore all databases (with master)?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot run/install SQL Server 2008 or any other production version on Linux OS, this is not allowed or possible, you can only install it on Windows server/client OS.

As per their official Blog, Microsoft announced in March 2016 that is planning to launch SQL Server on Linux: [Announcing SQL Server on Linux](https://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2016/03/07/announcing-sql-server-on-linux/#sm.0011yorfw1e6cd1rszs1k6vdt2ta7). The SQL Server version is currently called v.next and will be available on Linux. Tentative date for release is Mid 2017.

There is a public preview version that can be installed/tested now but is not production ready yet: [Take a closer look at SQL Server on Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql-server/sql-server-vnext-including-Linux)

Comment: Once you've got your SQL Server running on Linux, have you though about how you're going to transfer your DB objects and data over to the new instance?  You may want to take a look at Navicat Premium.  It can connect to both instances at the same time.  From there, you can literally drag over database objects in the GUI to copy them over.  There's are also Data Transfer and Synchronization tools that make it super easy to synchronize your data.  It comes with a fully functional 14 day trial. I also noticed that it's 30% off right now for the holidays.